# Canceling a ASIHTTPRequest - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to send request to web server. It all works fine. But now, when i call the `grabURLInBackground` method, a request is sent to the given URL.

But now, i need to cancel the request (as in stop sending, and stop downloading the content from the URL), in the `viewWillDissapear` method. How can i do this ? Help

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.operations)
{
    [req cancel];
    [req setDelegate:nil];
}
```

this should cancel it..

Comment: I am not using `Queue` in `ASIHTTPRequest` in my application. So can i use your code ?

Comment: What hapence if i use it in the VIewDidDissapear or ViewDidUnload? I have a tab bar controller, so while the request is running, if a user clicks on another bar, i need to cancel the request. Do you think if its ideal to use your code to solve it ?

Comment: refined comment: internally it uses NSOperationQueue if you don't use your own queue.. I think it should work.. but only use it in viewDidDisappear or otherwise it may cancel other requests from other viewcontrollers if you are using any.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
[request cancel]
```

Or:

```
[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
```

As can be seen in the documentation [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).

I'd suggest storing a reference to that request so you can cancel it when leaving the view.

Comment: what do you think about @AnkitSrivastava's answer, Will it cancel the request without having to store a reference of the request ?

Comment: Yeah it's a good method, that is ASIHTTPRequest's shared queue of all requests running. Unless you are running other requests and just want to cancel that one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and response it sure did help

Answer (score 2):

GOt thsi from ASIHttp docs:

Cancelling an asynchronous request

To cancel an asynchronous request (either a request that was started with [request startAsynchronous] or a request running in a queue you created), call [request cancel]. Note that you cannot cancel a synchronous request.

Note that when you cancel a request, the request will treat that as an error, and will call your delegate and/or queue’s failure delegate method. If you do not want this behaviour, set your delegate to nil before calling cancel, or use the clearDelegatesAndCancel method instead.

// Cancels an asynchronous request

[request cancel]

// Cancels an asynchronous request,

clearing all delegates and blocks first
[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];When using an ASINetworkQueue, all other requests will be cancelled when you cancel an individual request unless the queue’s shouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure is NO (YES is the default).

// When a request in this queue fails or is cancelled, other requests will continue to run

[queue setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO];

// Cancel all requests in a queue

[queue cancelAllOperations];

Comment: "When using an ASINetworkQueue, all other requests will be cancelled when you cancel an individual request unless the queue’s shouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure is NO (YES is the default)." -- this was crucial, I was trying to work out why all my requests were being killed when I cancelled one.